# Upgrade Apache Spark version from 1.6 to 2.0

Tags: apache-spark

Currently I have Spark version 1.6.2 installed.

I want to upgrade the Spark version to the newest 2.0.1. How do I do this without losing the existing configurations?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Download it? Spark isn't really "installed" since it just runs from an extracted archive from their site. Warning: Your code won't "just work" after you update 1.6.x to 2.x

Comment: If you just installed spark as standalone, you just need to install another version into your local.

Answer (score 0):

If its maven or sbt application you simply change dependency version of spark and also migrate your code according to 2.0 so you will not lose you configurations. and for spark binary you can take backup of config folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no much change related to configuration, some method signatures are changed , major changes i observed was mapPartitions method signature and some changes to metrics/listener api, apart from new features.